# Adding shadow effect in JButton

Tags: java, javafx, jbutton

Here is a basic question. I want to add shadow in my button of JButton. I can add shadow in javaFX easily, but in JButton i find it confusing. Is there any way to create shadow effect in a button of JButton using javaFX(not javaFX 2) ?

Comment: `JButton` is a swing component and nothing to do with JavaFX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `JavaFx` you should use `Button` rather than `JButton`(`Swing` component). You can set shadow programatically, e.g.:

```
DropShadow shadow = new DropShadow();
Button button = new Button();
button.setEffect(shadow);
```

Here's a [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/effect/DropShadow.html) to JavaDoc about `DropShadow`, may come in handy for you.